# how to upload chunks of a string longer than 2147483647 bytes?

Tags: python

I am trying to upload a file around ~5GB size as below but, it throws the error `string longer than 2147483647 bytes`. It sounds like there is a limit of 2 GB to upload. Is there a way to upload data in chunks? Can anyone provide guidance?

```
logger.debug(attachment_path)
currdir = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(attachment_path))
headers = self._headers
headers['Content-Type'] = content_type
headers['X-Override-File'] = 'true'
if not os.path.exists(attachment_path):
    raise Exception, "File path was invalid, no file found at the path %s" % attachment_path
filesize = os.path.getsize(attachment_path) 
fileToUpload = open(attachment_path, 'rb').read()
logger.info(filesize)
logger.debug(headers)
r = requests.put(self._baseurl + 'problems/' + problemID + "/" + attachment_type + "/" + urllib.quote(os.path.basename(attachment_path)), 
                 headers=headers,data=fileToUpload,timeout=300)
```

ERROR:

```
string longer than 2147483647 bytes
```

UPDATE:

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object,chunk_size=30720*30720):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while True:
        data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
        if not data:
            break
        yield data
        f = open(attachment_path)

for piece in read_in_chunks(f):
      r = requests.put(self._baseurl + 'problems/' + problemID + "/" + attachment_type + "/" + urllib.quote(os.path.basename(attachment_path)), 
                        headers=headers,data=piece,timeout=300)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question has been asked [on the `requests` bug tracker](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2717); their suggestion is to use [streaming upload](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-uploads). If that doesn't work, you might see if a [chunk-encoded request](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#chunk-encoded-requests) works.

[edit]

Example based on the original code:

```
# Using `with` here will handle closing the file implicitly
with open(attachment_path, 'rb') as file_to_upload:
    r = requests.put(
        "{base}problems/{pid}/{atype}/{path}".format(
            base=self._baseurl,
            # It's better to use consistent naming; search PEP-8 for standard Python conventions.
            pid=problem_id,
            atype=attachment_type,
            path=urllib.quote(os.path.basename(attachment_path)),
        ),
        headers=headers,
        # Note that you're passing the file object, NOT the contents of the file:
        data=file_to_upload,
        # Hard to say whether this is a good idea with a large file upload
        timeout=300,
    )
```

I can't guarantee this would run as-is, since I can't realistically test it, but it should be close. The bug tracker comments I linked to also mention that [sending multiple headers may cause issues](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/2717#issuecomment-252729478), so if the headers you're specifying are actually necessary, this may not work.

Regarding chunk encoding: This should be your second choice. Your code was not specifying `'rb'` as the mode for `open(...)`, so changing that should probably make the code above work. If not, you could try this.

```
def read_in_chunks():
    # If you're going to chunk anyway, doesn't it seem like smaller ones than this would be a good idea?
    chunk_size = 30720 * 30720

    # I don't know how correct this is; if it doesn't work as expected, you'll need to debug
    with open(attachment_path, 'rb') as file_object:
        while True:
            data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
            if not data:
                break
            yield data


# Same request as above, just using the function to chunk explicitly; see the `data` param
r = requests.put(
    "{base}problems/{pid}/{atype}/{path}".format(
        base=self._baseurl,
        pid=problem_id,
        atype=attachment_type,
        path=urllib.quote(os.path.basename(attachment_path)),
    ),
    headers=headers,
    # Call the chunk function here and the request will be chunked as you specify
    data=read_in_chunks(),
    timeout=300,
)
```

Comment: I took your suggestion and tried this but somehow it just hangs,I updated my code,what could be going wrong?

Comment: It's not clear that you understand the suggested solution. You should not be iterating over chunks and creating separate requests for them; you should be passing your generator to a single request as the `data` parameter. I'll update with an example based on your original code and the links I provided.

Comment: I tried second option and it does upload but it throws error` ('Connection aborted.', error(32, 'Broken pipe'))`

Comment: am able to see that option #1 works after retries ,it eventually does upload but I see errors `No JSON object could be decoded` ,why am I getting this error, how to fix this?

Comment: I don't know; it'd be impossible to guess without further information. I would suggest you create a different question with the relevant information and code.

Comment: what information you need?I dont think a different question is needed, its the exact same question which doesnt have a solution yet...

Comment: No, this question is about getting a 'string too large' error. That appears to have been solved. What you're talking about seems to be the response you're getting not being JSON; that's a separate issue, and it's not something I can address in comments. If you accept this answer and open a new question, I will gladly take a look, and I'm sure others will as well. But do leave this one here as a reference for others who might have the same issue; that's a big part of the value of StackOverflow.

Comment: I dont think its solved,it just manifested into another error and I am not sure if its working with this error so unable to accept the answer....

Comment: @user2125827 your *new* error basically indicate something is wrong on the server side, the original client side error has well-addressed with this answer.